# How to decide number of hidden layers and number of neurons for Autoencoder for dimensionality reduction function?

Tags: neural-networks, python, dimensionality-reduction, keras

I have been looking into deep learning and what caught my attention is the implementation of Autoencoder as a dimensionality reduction function for anomaly detection. I found out about it through the following link: [Machine learning for anomaly detection and condition monitoring](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-anomaly-detection-and-condition-monitoring-d4614e7de770). I tried to modify my code to fit for my case where I have 5 cases in total with two datasets where the first dataset I have 50 rows and 7 columns and second dataset I have the same number of rows but 10 columns. Every 10 rows represent a case and the first case is used as training and the rest as a test dataframe. The thing I am stuck as to how to decide the number of layers and number of neurons. How can I create Autoencoder to be used for detecting anomalies?

Find below my current approach for my model.

Code:

```
from numpy.random import seed
from tensorflow.random import set_seed as set_random_seed
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Dense 
from keras.models import Model, Sequential, load_model
from keras import regularizers
from keras.models import model_from_json
import theano.tensor as tt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

try:
    ## Using AutoEncoder Nueral Network:
    data_train_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Label'] == 'Training']
    data_test_df_C1 = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Label'] == 'Case1']
    data_test_df_C2 = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Label'] == 'Case2']
    data_test_df_C3 = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Label'] == 'Case3']
    data_test_df_C4 = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Label'] == 'Case4']
    
    # Separating and concentrating on features:
    data_train_df.drop(['Label', 'Tran_Label'], inplace=True, axis=1)
    data_test_df_C1.drop(['Label', 'Tran_Label'], inplace=True, axis=1)
    data_test_df_C2.drop(['Label', 'Tran_Label'], inplace=True, axis=1)
    data_test_df_C3.drop(['Label', 'Tran_Label'], inplace=True, axis=1)
    data_test_df_C4.drop(['Label', 'Tran_Label'], inplace=True, axis=1)    
    
    # Getting array of dataframes:
    data_train = np.array(data_train_df.values)
    data_test_C1 = np.array(data_test_df_C1.values)
    data_test_C2 = np.array(data_test_df_C2.values)
    data_test_C3 = np.array(data_test_df_C3.values)
    data_test_C4 = np.array(data_test_df_C4.values)
    
    # # Getting the covariance, its inverse matrix and mean of the training data for MD:
    seed(10)
    set_random_seed(10)
    act_func = 'elu'
    
    # Input layer:
    model=Sequential()
    # First hidden layer, connected to input vector X. 
    # # Test 1:
    # model.add(Dense(10,activation=act_func, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0), input_shape=(data_train.shape[1],)))
    # model.add(Dense(2,activation=act_func, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    # model.add(Dense(10,activation=act_func, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    # model.add(Dense(data_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    # model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
    
    # Test 2:
    model.add(Dense(6,activation=act_func, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0), input_shape=(data_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Dense(2,activation=act_func, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(6,activation=act_func, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(data_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
    
    # Train model for 100 epochs, batch size of 10: 
    NUM_EPOCHS=150
    BATCH_SIZE=10
    
    # Fitting the model:
    history=model.fit(data_train_df,data_train_df, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_split=0.05, verbose = 1)
    
    # Plotting the model's training losses:
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], 'b', label='Training loss')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], 'r', label='Validation loss')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Loss, [mse]')
    # plt.ylim([0,.1])
    plt.show()
    
    # Distribution of loss function in the training set:
    data_pred = model.predict(np.array(data_train))
    data_pred = pd.DataFrame(data_pred)
    data_pred.index = data_train_df.index
    
    scored = pd.DataFrame(index=data_train_df.index)
    scored['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(data_pred-data_train), axis = 1)
    plt.figure()
    sns.distplot(scored['Loss_mae'], bins = 10, kde= True, color = 'blue')
    plot = sns.distplot(scored['Loss_mae'], bins = 10, kde= True, color = 'blue').get_lines()[0].get_data()
    # plt.xlim(0.0, max(plot[0]))
    plt.show()

    data_pred = model.predict(np.array(data_test_C1))
    data_pred = pd.DataFrame(data_pred)
    data_pred.index = data_test_df_C1.index
    
    scored_C1 = pd.DataFrame(index=data_test_df_C1.index)
    scored_C1['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(data_pred-data_test_C1), axis = 1)
    scored_C1['Threshold'] = max(plot[0])
    scored_C1['Anomaly'] = scored_C1['Loss_mae'] > scored_C1['Threshold']
    scored_C1['Case'] = '1 Case'
    scored_C1.head()
    
    data_pred_train = model.predict(np.array(data_train))
    data_pred_train = pd.DataFrame(data_pred_train)
    data_pred_train.index = data_train_df.index
    
    scored_train = pd.DataFrame(index=data_train_df.index)
    scored_train['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(data_pred_train-data_train), axis = 1)
    scored_train['Threshold'] = max(plot[0])
    scored_train['Anomaly'] = scored_train['Loss_mae'] > scored_train['Threshold']
    scored_train['Case'] = '0 Case'

    data_pred = model.predict(np.array(data_test_C2))
    data_pred = pd.DataFrame(data_pred)
    data_pred.index = data_test_df_C2.index

    scored_C2 = pd.DataFrame(index=data_test_df_C2.index)
    scored_C2['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(data_pred-data_test_C2), axis = 1)
    scored_C2['Threshold'] = max(plot[0])
    scored_C2['Anomaly'] = scored_C2['Loss_mae'] > scored_C2['Threshold']
    scored_C2['Case'] = '2 Case'
    scored_C2.head()
    
    data_pred = model.predict(np.array(data_test_C3))
    data_pred = pd.DataFrame(data_pred)
    data_pred.index = data_test_df_C3.index
    
    scored_C3 = pd.DataFrame(index=data_test_df_C3.index)
    scored_C3['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(data_pred-data_test_C3), axis = 1)
    scored_C3['Threshold'] = max(plot[0])
    scored_C3['Anomaly'] = scored_C3['Loss_mae'] > scored_C3['Threshold']
    scored_C3['Case'] = '3 Case'
    scored_C3.head()
    
    data_pred = model.predict(np.array(data_test_C4))
    data_pred = pd.DataFrame(data_pred)
    data_pred.index = data_test_df_C4.index
    
    scored_C4 = pd.DataFrame(index=data_test_df_C4.index)
    scored_C4['Loss_mae'] = np.mean(np.abs(data_pred-data_test_C4), axis = 1)
    scored_C4['Threshold'] = max(plot[0])
    scored_C4['Anomaly'] = scored_C4['Loss_mae'] > scored_C4['Threshold']
    scored_C4['Case'] = '4 Case'
    scored_C4.head()
    
    # scored = pd.concat([scored_train, scored], copy=False)
    # scored = scored_train.append(scored)    
    # scored_list.append(scored)

    final_scored = pd.concat([scored_train, scored_C1, scored_C2, scored_C3, scored_C4])
    print(final_scored)

except Exception as e:
    print('Cause of the error:')
    print(e)
    print('Cannot implement Anomaly detection using Autoencoder')
    pass
```

*Side Question/s:*

- Is there a way to decide the number of epochs and batch size?

Comment: What is the purpose of using autoencoder? If you have that little data, using any neural network is rather pointless, why not using simpler algorithm?

Comment: Forget about autoencoders, use PCA or something equally simple

Comment: @Aksakal I already did and it worked. I just wanted to test the neural network to see if I can manage to get it to work as well, because I might be thinking of using neural network soon, so, I wanted to learn about the parameters used in neural network.